# Angular Material does not tracked?

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I'm using Angular Material to use tabs. When I work in local the web works fine, but if I upload to git and download a new copy, the tabs doesn't work and I don't know why it is. Anyone?

Comment: No, nothing is empty...

Comment: i also faced the same issue, are you using the cdn or installed using bower?

Comment: No, I installed it with npm

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. I have some directory added to my .gitignore and was not uploaded to my repository.